# Ruby - FileUtils - dereference_root option

Tags: ruby, dereference, fileutils

Can someone explain me exactly (better if with examples) the meaning of the dereference_root option in FileUtils.cp_r and in other class method of the same class?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It applies **only** if your source file/directory is **symbolic link**. If it is and you specify this option, then `FileUtils.cp_r` will follow this link and copy the *original files* otherwise you will get just a copy of the symlink.

**But this doesn't apply recursively.** So if you will have other symlinks inside your source folder they will be just copied as is, without 'dereferencing'.

Comment: So how do you get it recursively?